# Windows 11 - can't create a public key with SSH-Keygen

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I am trying to create a key with `ssh-keygen` but none of the keys is considered fitting when I try to use in GitHub (unless I am getting it wrong). Posting examples below.

This is my `id_rsa` file:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3Blbn[…]
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And this is my `.pub` file:

```
ssh-rsa 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
```

If I am making a mistake, where exactly? If not, then what can be the issue?
Thanks everyone in advance

Comment: how exactly are you trying to *`use in github`*?

Comment: Note the private key is supposed to be private. You have compromised your private key by publishing it here. Now anyone can use it. Whatever service/server/OS/anything you had set up to accept this exact key may be compromised. Withdraw the key from everywhere; make sure no rogue has accessed your assets (and maybe has set up a way to keep accessing it after you withdraw the key! in general [this is non-trivial](https://serverfault.com/q/218005)); never use this keypair again.

Comment: @Bravo from here, copy and pasting my public key https://github.com/settings/keys

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks for heads up, I had already withdrew even before I posted it here!

Comment: `here` - I figured out that bit, `copy and pasting my public key` that's the part I was asking about, and what error are you getting, exactly?